# Display two arrays in foreach loop in Php?

Tags: php, loops, yii, foreach

I want to display data in single foreach loop. I have two tables `dailystats` and `monthlystats` both of them have same columns like `calls`,`minutes`,`incomingcalls` etc Im using Yii PHP Framework Here is my controller

```
public function actionViewStats(){
    $model = new Company();
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $modelMonthly = $model->getCompanyUsageMonthly($id);
    $modelDaily = $model->getCompanyUsageDaily($id);

    $this->renderPartial('/shared/_company_stats', array(
        'modelDaily' => $modelDaily,
        'modelMonthly'=>$modelMonthly
        ));
}
```

Here is my view of table.

```
       <?PHP  if(isset($modelMonthly) && sizeof($modelMonthly)!=0): ?>
            <div class="ibox-content col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="title col-md-2">
                    <h3>Current Usage</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">

                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                            <th>Minutes</th>
                            <th>Incoming Minutes</th>
                            <th>Calls</th>
                            <th>Incoming Calls</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <?PHP
                            if(isset($modelMonthly)){
                                foreach($modelMonthly as $monthlystats){
                                    ?>
                                    <tr>

                                        <td><?php echo $monthlystats->minutes?></td>
                                        <td><?PHP echo $monthlystats->incoming_minutes; ?></td>

                                        <td><?PHP echo $monthlystats->calls; ?></td>
                                        <td><?PHP echo $monthlystats->incoming_calls; ?></td>

                                    </tr>
                                <?PHP } } ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?PHP endif;?>
```

This is showing only monthly stats `modelMonthly` but i want to show daily stats `modelDaily` too in the same foreach loop.. How do i do that? I have tried array_combine etc but unable to do it. Searched on SOF but unable to find solution for it.

My code above shows only Monthly stats like this

[image]

But I want to show like this below. I have already made the table but im not able to use both `modelDaily` and `modelMonthly` in same foreach loop. I have tried different things but unable to do it..

[image]

```
<?PHP
                                if(isset($modelMonthly)){
                                    foreach($modelMonthly as $usage){
                                        ?>
                                        <tr>

                                            <td><?php echo $usage->minutes?></td>
                                            <td><?PHP echo $usage->incoming_minutes; ?></td>

                                            <td><?PHP echo $usage->calls; ?></td>
                                            <td><?PHP echo $usage->incoming_calls; ?></td>

                                        </tr>
                                    <?PHP } } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both your arrays have numerical indexes, you can use a regular `for` loop:

```php
for ($i = 0; $i < max(count($modelMonthly), count($modelDaily)); $i) {
     if (isset($modelDaily[$i]) {
         // Add the daily columns
     } else {
         // Add as much empty columns
     }
     if (isset($modelMonthly[$i]) {
         // Add the monthly columns
     } else {
         // Add as much empty columns
     }
}
```

The next step is adding the required headers `th` in the `thead`, and adding the extra `td` inside the loop.

---

Alternatively, you can create both table independantly, and position them using CSS. It is not in the scope of this question, but this is what I would recommend.

Comment: Perfect. I got hint from your both answers `for loop` and `alternative` one, Instead of using two tables independently, I used `one table` with `two foreach loops` inside `if else loop` just like your above answer

Comment: Glad I've been of use, you can mark my answer as accepted for the sake of clarity (and more Brownie points for me!).

Answer (score 0):

You shoudl use this tecnique

```
foreach($modelMonthly as $index => $usage){
        ?>
        <tr>

            <td><?php echo $usage->minutes?></td>
            <td><?PHP echo $usage->incoming_minutes; ?></td>

            <td><?PHP echo $usage->calls; ?></td>
            <td><?PHP echo $usage->incoming_calls; ?></td>

            <td><?php if (isset($dailystats[$index]->minute)) echo $dailystats[$index]->minutes?></td>
            <td><?PHP if (isset($dailystats[$index]->incoming_minutes)) echo $dailystats[$index]->incoming_minutes; ?></td>

            <td><?PHP if (isset($dailystats[$index]->calls)) echo $dailystats[$index]->calls; ?></td>
            <td><?PHP if (isset($dailystats[$index]->incoming_calls)) echo $dailystats[$index]->incoming_calls; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?PHP } } ?>
```

Comment: This dangerously assume that both arrays have the same number of items. This may be true here, but you have no way of being sure.

Comment: @HypolitePetovan  yes .. with an isset is better